# Requesting Help for confusing block reduction techniques

Tags: control-engineering

[image]

[image]

I was solving a block reduction practice problem above.

How do I collapse this block diagram from this position?

I know I can swap Summation junctions, but Im stuck with the G3 branch inbetween my summation junction(s)

Comment: Is your manual sketch the starting point, and the first drawing the result? Or vice versa?

Comment: Instead of shifting $G_1$ to the right of the summing junction, shift $G_2$ to te left. This will make $G_3$ parallel to $G_1.G_2$. if you try is out, let us know the result by editing the details of that attempt by using the [edit] option below the question.